# caffe could not open or find file

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm new to caffe and after successfully running an example I'm trying to use my own data. However, when trying to either write my data into the lmdb data format or directly trying to use the solver, in both cases I get the error:

```
E0201 14:26:00.450629 13235 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file ~/Documents/ChessgameCNN/input/train/731_1.bmp 731
```

The path is right, but it's weird that the label `731` is part of this error message. That implies that it's reading it as part of the path instead of as a label. The text file looks like this:

```
~/Documents/ChessgameCNN/input/train/731_1.bmp 731
```

Is it because the labels are too high? Or maybe because the labels don't start with 0? I've searched for this error and all I found were examples with relatively few labels, about ~1-5, but I have about 4096 classes of which I don't always actually have examples in the training data. Maybe this is a problem, too (certainly for learning, at least, but I didn't expect for it to give me an actual error message). Usually, the label does not seem to be part of this error message.
For the creation of the lmdb  file, I use the `create_imagenet.sh` from the caffe examples. For solving, I use:

```
~/caffe/build/tools/caffe train --solver ~/Documents/ChessgameCNN/caffe_models/caffe_model_1/solver_1.prototxt 2>&1 | tee ~/Documents/ChessgameCNN/caffe_models/caffe_model_1/model_1_train.log
```

I tried different image data types, too: PNG, JPEG and BMP. So this isn't the culprit, either.
If it is really because of my choice of labels, what would be a viable workaround for this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: do you get this error while creating the `lmdb`, or when you train the net? what command were you used to create the `lmdb`? can you post the prototxt of the input layer you are using in your net?

Comment: if you have no training samples of a certain label - why having this label in the first place?! labels should start from zero and go up to the number of classes you actually have in your training data.

Comment: I get this error in both cases - whether I try to solve the data "raw" or trying to create a lmdb file. As said, I simply used the `create_imagenet.sh` with paths to my data instead of the data from the imagenet example. The labels are all possible moves, and I wanted to try a smaller data set first just to get it working and then move to bigger data sets, so not every *possible* move might be in that specific set.

Comment: having the same problem here...and i noticed the problem rise when i use the different size images....havent fixed it yet

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Check that lines in your text file don't have spaces in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem with *convert_imageset*. I have solved just removing the trailing spaces in the text file which contains the labels.